# More reputation when answering a good question

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't answering complex questions get more upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43360/shouldnt-answering-complex-questions-get-more-upvotes)

I'm still quite new to Stack Exchange, so I'm hoping this suggestion makes sense.

Consider the following scenario:

- A user posts a question.
- Several users view the question, find it really interesting but can't answer it, so they upvote it.
- They don't find it interesting enough however to favorite it.
- Somebody answers the question, but doesn't get that many upvotes for it.

Wouldn't it be interesting for the person that can answer the question, to get a bigger reputation award, based on how many upvotes the question has? This would give extra incentive to answer a difficult question.

The other way around it would work as well. A very basic, easy to answer question, wouldn't earn as much reputation easily. This would solve the 'inbalance' of easy questions earning as much reputation as difficult questions.

Right now, only 'popular' good answers give you a lot of reputation.

UPDATE:

To prevent answers on [questions like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/231161/what-is-this-thing-called) to get a lot of reputation for nothing, a solution would be to only apply this mechanism as long as an answer hasn't been accepted. At the point the answer is accepted, the 'extra' rep could be added.

Comment: and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49412/should-answers-to-old-questions-get-more-or-less-reputation-points

Comment: @Juan Manuel: Possibly, I didn't find that one when searching. I do propose a possible solution however, where the other post only states the problem. Should I post it as a reply there instead?

Comment: You can do both, my vote to close is only my opinion. 4 more are needed to actually close this one.

Comment: Toward your edit: that question got a ton of votes before the OP accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not based on your criteria of number of votes.

I give you [**this question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/231161/what-is-this-thing-called) on SF as a prime example.  I would NOT want someone who answers this to get more rep just because 113 of us (currently) were having a very Fridayish Friday.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with your primary argument that difficult questions get more upvotes. I have seen some really lame questions get lots of upvotes. I don't think that what you propose would make things better, in fact I fear that while your intentions are good, it might actually make things much worse, because people would tend to look for only highly upvoted questions, meaning new questions get *less* attention and *less* upvotes.

Comment: So, perhaps only apply it as long as the question isn't answered.